How do I keep 'Extended Features' enabled when saving a PDF that was edited using PikePDF?
I am attempting to edit the contents of a PDF file using PikePDF in Python. The unmodified PDF file has "Extended features" enabled which allows the form in the document to be fill-able within Adobe Reader. If I open the document using PikePDF and then save the document, these 'Extended Features' will be disabled:
with pikepdf.Pdf.open(file) as pdfData:
pdfData.save(file)
Is there any way to open and then save a pdf in Python while preserving the "Extended Features" option?
I have tried various arguments in pikepdf.Pdf.save but nothing has stopped the feature from being disabled.
